# How do I override a field template?

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to override a field template with my own one. The field is called field_test, so I created a field--field-test--mynodetype.html.twig template file ` in root-theme-directory/templates/, but Drupal doesn't recognize it.

I cleared the cache from the UI, enabled debug mode in settings.yaml, installed the Devel module, and re-generate the theme registry on each request, but nothing seems to help. The field gets always rendered with the default field.html.twig template.

How do I override the field template Drupal uses?

Comment: Just for posterity have you tried `field--field_test--mynodetype.html.twig`? (underscore in field name)

Comment: Did you use the twig debug output (HTML comments) to figure out the template name? I'm seeing a template suggestion that looks more like `field--node--field-image--article.html.twig` (note the possibly missing 'node' from your template name).

Comment: Some docs for that are here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2358785 if that works for you I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Cottser Alright this has solved my problem. The missing `node--` was the problem. Thx :-). But then this doc needs update here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!field.html.twig/8

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER - great. I will make sure an issue gets created to fix those docs.

Comment: Here is the issue I promised for fixing the documentation in field.html.twig: https://www.drupal.org/node/2396553

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to specify the [entity type](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/entity) (node, taxonomy_term, ...) in the template name suggestion as you specified, i.e. field--node--field-test.html.twig.

*node* is the entity type, and *field-test* is the field name.

If you want to know which template is generating a particular markup element, you can use Twig's debug option. You enable Twig debugging in sites/default/services.yml; set the value of `debug` in `twig.config` to `true`.

I have added the *field_test* field to the *Article* nodes, and I got the [template suggestions in the HTML source](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392).

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--node--field-test--article.html.twig
   * field--node--field-test.html.twig
   * field--node--article.html.twig
   * field--field-test.html.twig
   * field--string.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
```

After getting the suggestion, I created a template file and kept this in the templates directory of the theme.

Remember to clear the cache.

See [Working With Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2186401) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Templates *must* be placed in a 'templates' directory in your theme. They won't be picked up in the root of your theme. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2349803#templates (which I just updated to note the difference from the Drupal 7 behaviour).

Comment: Good point, but sorry that forgot to mention that I've put them already in a folder called `templates`. I mean other template overrides work. So I've overwritten the default `node.html.twig` which works fine. But I can't override fields.