# Rewrite a text field in "Manage display" of content type

Tags: nodes, 8, entities

This feels like it should be simple to do, but I can't work it out.

If I have a text field, how do I rewrite the output of the field on the "Manage display" tab of the content type? For example, I might want to add units, or convert a product ID into a link to an external website.

I know how to do this stuff in Views, but it would seem to make sense to be able to do it via the "Manage Display" tab for a content type. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating `field.html.twig`.

Default theme implementation for a field.

You will get more information:

[Override field template (twig)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136465/override-field-template-twig)

[field.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!field.html.twig/8.2.x) and [field--node--title.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!templates!field--node--title.html.twig/8.2.x)

Comment: This option was much easier than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of choice based on your needs:

1. Overriding the template file (twig) of the specific field
2. Using form_hook_alter
3. For complex and clean solution I suggest you to use a custom widget for your field type.

Comment: There are also some simple string formatter  contrib modules